# In what scenario will the queries that are being run on a table be stored with values as :1,:2,:3 in the sql_text field of v$sql

Tags: sql, plsql, triggers

I have tried to create a trigger that captures all the queries that are being run against a table and then stores the queries into a new table. In this process I have come across a case where the queries are getting stored as :

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COL1 = :1   WHERE COL2 = :2   AND COL3 = :3   AND COL4 = :4  

INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME VALUES(:1,:2,:3,:4).
```

The trigger is working fine for some scenarios where the entire DML statement is given but when its being through a stored procedure, its behaving in this way. The trigger basically scans the `v$sql` table to capture the `sql_text` field which has the query. 
Can you please tell me what I am missing here, let me know if anything else is to be added to help you answer this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: queries means get data result by select statement, I think you mean DML operations (insert, update, delete)

Comment: thats right, I am trying to do DML operations on the table.

Comment: please reformat your question to be more clear.

Comment: Are you trying to get the SQL statement *before* it was transformed into the bind variable format?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are after is

V$SQL_BIND_CAPTURE this for each sql statment this collects the bind variables (anything starting with a : in your output).

By joining this to V$SQL on SQL_ID you should be able to either rebuild the full sql or at the least get the sql with all of the values.

Cheers
Shaun Peterson

EDIT 1

Not sure what version of Oracle you are using, if you are using 11g r2 or above you could do somthing with listagg but I only have a 10g instance available at the moment so the below was written against that.

```
SELECT SQ.SQL_ID,
       SQ.SQL_TEXT,
       (SELECT RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E, NAME || ' =  ' || VALUE_STRING || ', ')).EXTRACT('//text()'),',') PARAMS  
        FROM V$SQL_BIND_CAPTURE 
        WHERE SQL_ID = '2xj19k2f4c2by') AS PARAMS
FROM V$SQL SQ
WHERE SQ.SQL_ID = '2xj19k2f4c2by';
```

This will give output like the below

```
SQL_ID             SQL_TEXT                                        PARAMS
2xj19k2f4c2by      INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME VALUES(:1,:2).           :1 = 'TEST', :2 = 123
```

You will pick up the sql_id as you are scanning through V$SQL table.

From here you can either just store the string and the params or go the next step and use regex to replace the bind parameters back into the SQL text.

Hope this helps.

Comment: can you please give me the entire DML statement or the query to get the full sql please ?